# Close or Delete Old Events in Calendar

Tags: solspace-calendar, newrelic

I recently added New Relic to my server to look at performance. It has been a lifesaver for finding issues. It's currently showing the events page that uses Calendar by Solspace has the highest load time by a huge margin (16.6 seconds at last check). Part of the issue is the methodology in which I display events which I'm attempting to improve. The other is the number of old events it has to look through. There are over 450 as of last count with most being outdated.

Is there a way to close or delete an event once it's completed?

I'm running:
EE 2.7.3
Calendar 1.8.5

Comment: I don't think you can programmatically‎ delete events, but the GUI on the Calendar Events entry editing tab allows for batch deleting. However, you shouldn't have to worry about old events; our `exp_calendar_events` table on our DB has 3791 entries as of this morning, and all of our load times are less than one or two seconds. It perhaps has more to do with how you're calling your events than anything else. Could you paste an example of how you typically implement `{exp:calendar:cal}`?

Comment: Sounds like you might benefit from some code/template optimization. If you can show your template code for Calendar, maybe there's something that can be improved. Calendar can be resource-intensive sometimes though, so caching may also be best solution.

Comment: Yeah, after that post I really delved back into the code and it's doing too much. There are 3 levels of event that have to be displayed. So it's looping through the active events 3 times based on different criteria. All 3 are embeds in the main template. Here's just one of them [link](https://gist.github.com/calvary/915b23a98161c619aadc#file-event-loop). I just added `cache="yes" refresh="10"` which helps a little. Now I just need to go back and rethink the whole process.